# SP2013: Do I need to install Workflow manager on WFE or APP server?

Tags: 2013, workflow

I am using SP2013. When I create a workflow in SP designer I do not see the 2013 platform. I need to install it by the Workflow manager. Do I need to install the workflow manager on the WFE or APP server?

Comment: on the sharepoint server, can you tell me what is diffrence between WFE and APP in your case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this slide](http://www.slideshare.net/roykimtoronto/development-server-workflow-manager-10-setup-reference), you can install Workflow manager on WFE server but you still need to install workflow client and go through procedure of configuring.

You will need to install Workflow manager client on all WFEs regardless of as if Workflow manager is installed and configured on App or WFE server.

This MSDN article will help you understand the concept, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658588(v=office.15).aspx

[Follow this post for steps.](http://blog.cloudshare.com/2013/01/15/how-to-install-and-configure-workflow-infrastructure-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: The slides you mentioned provides an idea on how to install Workflow Manager in a development environment, in which WFE and APP Server Functions are running on one single server. In production I recommend to install the Workflow Manager on a dedicated server or on your application server.

Comment: the "follow this post for step" link is 404. By any chance you can recover it?