# Install workflow manager in all the WFEs or Index Servers

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, installation, workflow-manager, appserver-index-server

My prod farm is going to be 2 WFEs, 2 INDEX servers and 1 sql cluster.
I  have to use SP 2013 WFs for my business requirement.

For this i need to configure workflow manager CU-2 in this farm. I have decided to install workflow manager CU2 refresh version on the Index server1.

My question is :

**Should i install this workflow manager in all the WFEs and INDEX servers?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SP2013: Do I need to install Workflow manager on WFE or APP server?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92361/sp2013-do-i-need-to-install-workflow-manager-on-wfe-or-app-server)

Comment: i think, it may not be a duplicate question, because my farm arch is  different compared to the question you have mentioned.

Comment: Which SharePoint version you are using and what is the Server OS?

Comment: Am using Win Server 2012 R2 OS, in all the WFEs , Index servers.Am using SP 2013 SP1 with April 2017 CU1 (N-1)

Answer (score 1):

I'd not do this for the following reasons:

- To be supported in a high-availability setup, you'll need to have *exactly* three workflow servers. Yes, you can collocate workflow manager onto SharePoint servers in the farm, but to end up with three servers hosting the workflow manager, you're going to differentially load the servers in the farm.
- If you don't want or need high-availability, then a single server is your option. Again you'd be differentially loading the servers in the farm.

If you could have either three WFE servers, they'd be candidates for collocating the workflow manager in HA mode, however at that point you're WFE servers are hosting (probably) the distributed cache and the workflow manager in addition to the normal SharePoint services and may require additional resources.

Do you have any option to provide servers dedicated to hosting the workflow manager?

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things, you have to decide between single server WFM or HA WFM (in HA only 3 Servers are supported). So WFM topology should be either 1 server farm or 3 servers.

If it is single Server farm then as a best practice **you can install the WFM on one of your WFE**. After this you have to make sure WFM client should install on all other servers in the farm ( WFE and App servers). If WFM client not installed on the other servers then WFM manage will through the errors.

But if you want to go with 3 server topology then you need a loadbalncer infront of them, and a SSL certificate. required a lot of extra works.

Most of the deployments are fine with 1 server WFM farm.

Comment: if i remember correctly in one of the questions posted here, Trevor Seward, MVP, suggested to install WFM on the INDEX SERVER and NOT on any of the WFEs. Thats why i have asked this question.

Comment: I am not sure because I never heard about it.  Only reason, i will not do on the Index server due to search. Once crawling under way which may hit the server's performance. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/97f33299-2c85-4cf2-929e-34c6507e9b60/workflow-manager-installation-in-sharepoint-2013